# Проблема с добавлением записи в json конфиг

Tags: python, json

Хочу работать с *json* файлом, но у меня не получается добавить новый объект для *json*. Выдаёт такую ошибку: `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'`

```
import json
from pathlib import Path
with open('config.json', encoding='utf-8') as fh: 
    data = json.load(fh)
    data['config'].append({'новая характеристика':'ее содержимое'})
    fh.write_text(json.dumps(data), encoding='utf-8')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы неправильно обрабатываете словарь:

```
data['config']['новая характеристика'] = 'ее содержимое'
```

то есть если вы хотите добавить новую пару `ключ - значение`, делается это так.

Answer (score 2):

`data['config']` у вас словарь, а вы пытаетесь добавить значение как будто это список. Для добавления нового элемента в словарь нужно записать значение по нужному ключу.

```
data['config']['новая характеристика'] = 'ее содержимое'
```

Если нужно в существующий словарь добавить данные из другого словаря, используйте метод `update`:

```
data['config'].update({
    'новая характеристика': 'ее содержимое',
    'еще одна характеристика': 'еще одно значение'
})
```